# $\sum_{k=1}^n a_k^3 = \left(\sum_{k=1}^n a_k \right)^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

We know that $\sum_{k=1}^n k^3 = \left(\sum_{k=1}^n k \right)^2$. Interestingly, $1^3+2^3+2^3+4^3=(1+2+2+4)^2$. Are there other non-consecutive numbers $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_k$ such that $$\sum_{k=1}^n a_k^3 = \left(\sum_{k=1}^n a_k \right)^2?$$

Comment: There is 2,2,4,4 and the trivial $a_k=n$ for all $k$.

Comment: related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1326966/is-there-any-general-method-for-solving-a-1a-2-a-n2-a-13a-23-a-n3

Answer (score 9):

Here is a surprising result:
$$
\sum_{d\mid n} \tau(d)^3 = \big(\sum_{d\mid n} \tau(d)\big)^2
$$
where $\tau$ counts the number of divisors of an integer.

It's exercise 12 in chapter 2 of Apostol's *Introduction to Analytic Number Theory*.

If you take $n=2^N$, you get the classic result for consecutive numbers.

If you take $n=pq$, a product of two primes, you get your example.

I don't think all examples come from the result above, though.

See John Mason, [Generalising 'Sums of Cubes Equal to Squares of Sums'](http://www.jstor.org/stable/3620469),
*The Mathematical Gazette*, Vol. 85, No. 502 (Mar., 2001), pp. 50-58.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I just saw another reference:David Pagni, 82.27 An Interesting Number Fact, The Mathematical Gazette, Vol. 82, No. 494 (Jul., 1998), pp. 271-273.

Comment: @pipi, yes, Mason starts by citing Pagni.

Answer (score 4):

Lots.  Here's some examples:

```
[ 2, 2 ]
[ 3, 3, 3 ]
[ 1, 2, 2, 4 ]
[ 2, 2, 4, 4 ]
[ 4, 4, 4, 4 ]
[ 1, 2, 2, 3, 5 ]
[ 3, 3, 3, 3, 6 ]
[ 3, 3, 3, 4, 6 ]
[ 5, 5, 5, 5, 5 ]
[ 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 5 ]
[ 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 5 ]
[ 1, 1, 2, 4, 5, 5 ]
[ 1, 1, 4, 5, 5, 5 ]
[ 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 6 ]
[ 1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 6 ]
[ 1, 4, 4, 4, 6, 6 ]
[ 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 6 ]
[ 2, 2, 4, 4, 6, 6 ]
[ 2, 4, 4, 5, 5, 7 ]
[ 2, 4, 4, 6, 6, 6 ]
[ 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 7 ]
[ 3, 3, 3, 6, 6, 6 ]
[ 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7 ]
[ 3, 5, 5, 5, 6, 7 ]
[ 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7 ]
[ 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6 ]
[ 1, 1, 2, 2, 5, 5, 6 ]
[ 1, 1, 3, 4, 4, 5, 7 ]
[ 1, 1, 4, 5, 5, 5, 7 ]
[ 1, 1, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6 ]
[ 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 6, 6 ]
[ 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 7 ]
[ 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7 ]
[ 1, 2, 2, 4, 6, 6, 6 ]
[ 1, 2, 3, 6, 6, 6, 6 ]
[ 1, 2, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6 ]
[ 1, 3, 5, 5, 5, 7, 7 ]
[ 1, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7 ]
[ 1, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7 ]
[ 2, 2, 2, 2, 5, 5, 7 ]
[ 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8 ]
[ 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 8 ]
[ 2, 3, 3, 3, 5, 7, 7 ]
[ 2, 3, 3, 5, 6, 7, 7 ]
[ 2, 3, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7 ]
[ 2, 4, 4, 6, 6, 6, 8 ]
[ 2, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 8 ]
[ 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 6, 8 ]
[ 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 6, 8 ]
[ 3, 3, 3, 4, 6, 6, 8 ]
[ 3, 5, 5, 5, 7, 7, 8 ]
[ 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 9 ]
[ 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 9 ]
[ 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 9 ]
[ 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7 ]
[ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 5 ]
[ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 6 ]
[ 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 5, 6 ]
[ 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 5, 6, 6 ]
[ 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 5, 6, 6 ]
[ 1, 1, 1, 2, 5, 5, 5, 7 ]
[ 1, 1, 1, 2, 5, 6, 6, 6 ]
[ 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 7 ]
[ 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7 ]
[ 1, 1, 2, 4, 4, 5, 5, 8 ]
[ 1, 1, 2, 4, 5, 5, 5, 8 ]
[ 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 8 ]
[ 1, 1, 4, 5, 5, 5, 7, 8 ]
[ 1, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 8 ]
[ 1, 2, 2, 2, 4, 5, 7, 7 ]
[ 1, 2, 2, 2, 5, 5, 7, 7 ]
[ 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 7, 7 ]
[ 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 6, 8 ]
[ 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8 ]
[ 1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 6, 6, 8 ]
[ 1, 2, 2, 5, 5, 7, 7, 7 ]
[ 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 7, 7, 7 ]
[ 1, 2, 4, 5, 5, 7, 7, 8 ]
[ 1, 2, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8 ]
[ 1, 2, 5, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7 ]
[ 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 7, 8 ]
[ 1, 3, 3, 3, 6, 6, 7, 8 ]
[ 1, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 8, 8 ]
[ 1, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 8, 8 ]
[ 1, 3, 4, 6, 6, 6, 8, 8 ]
[ 1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8 ]
[ 1, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 7, 9 ]
[ 1, 4, 4, 6, 6, 6, 7, 9 ]
[ 1, 4, 5, 5, 7, 7, 8, 8 ]
[ 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8 ]
[ 1, 5, 5, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8 ]
[ 1, 6, 6, 6, 6, 8, 8, 8 ]
[ 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 8 ]
[ 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 6, 7, 7 ]
[ 2, 2, 2, 3, 5, 5, 7, 8 ]
[ 2, 2, 2, 3, 6, 7, 7, 7 ]
[ 2, 2, 2, 5, 7, 7, 7, 7 ]
[ 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 9 ]
[ 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 7, 7, 8 ]
[ 2, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 7, 8 ]
[ 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 8 ]
[ 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 6, 6, 9 ]
[ 2, 2, 4, 4, 6, 6, 6, 9 ]
[ 2, 2, 4, 4, 6, 6, 8, 8 ]
[ 2, 2, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8 ]
[ 2, 2, 5, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8 ]
[ 2, 2, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8 ]
[ 2, 3, 3, 5, 5, 6, 7, 9 ]
[ 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 7, 7, 9 ]
[ 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8 ]
[ 2, 3, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8 ]
[ 2, 4, 4, 6, 6, 6, 8, 9 ]
[ 2, 4, 6, 6, 6, 7, 8, 9 ]
[ 2, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 10 ]
[ 2, 5, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 9 ]
[ 2, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 10 ]
[ 2, 6, 6, 6, 8, 8, 8, 8 ]
[ 2, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8 ]
[ 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 6, 6, 9 ]
[ 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9 ]
[ 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9 ]
[ 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 7, 8, 8 ]
[ 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9 ]
[ 3, 3, 5, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8 ]
[ 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 7, 10 ]
[ 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 10 ]
[ 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 8, 8, 9 ]
[ 3, 4, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 9 ]
[ 3, 5, 5, 5, 6, 7, 7, 10 ]
[ 3, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 9, 9 ]
[ 3, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 10 ]
[ 3, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9 ]
[ 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 6, 10 ]
[ 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 7, 10 ]
[ 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 8, 8, 8 ]
[ 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 9, 9 ]
[ 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 9, 9 ]
[ 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 7, 9, 9 ]
[ 4, 4, 6, 6, 7, 7, 9, 9 ]
[ 4, 5, 5, 5, 8, 8, 8, 9 ]
[ 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8, 10 ]
[ 4, 6, 6, 6, 7, 8, 9, 9 ]
[ 5, 5, 5, 7, 7, 7, 8, 10 ]
[ 5, 5, 7, 7, 7, 8, 9, 9 ]
[ 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 9, 10 ]
[ 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9 ]
[ 6, 6, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9 ]
[ 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8 ]
```

This was generated by the [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org/) code:

```
for s in [1..8] do
  A:=UnorderedTuples([1..20],s);;
  for L in A do
    lhs:=Sum(List(L,n->n^3));
    rhs:=Sum(L)^2;
    if(lhs=rhs and L<>[1..s]) then Print(L,"\n"); fi;
  od;
od;
```

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible that $$\sum_{k=1}^n a_k^3 = \left(\sum_{k=1}^n a_k \right)^2$$ with some $a_k>n$?

Comment: Yes, there's some in the list above, such as `[ 3, 3, 3, 3, 6 ]` and `[ 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 9 ]`.

Comment: Oh ya, I did not notice it! Thanks!