# Prove that if $n \in \mathbb{N}$, then $\sum_{d|n}{(d(n))^3}=(\sum_{d|n}{d(n)})^2$ where $d(n)$ is the divisor function.

Tags: number-theory

Prove that if $n \in \mathbb{N}$, then $$\sum_{d|n}{(d(n))^3}=(\sum_{d|n}{d(n)})^2$$ where $d(n)$ is the divisor function. I have know only information is $d(n)=\sum_{d|n}{1}$.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/a/216698/589.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Outline:** Let $f(n)$ be the function on the left, and $g(n)$ the function on the right.

Both $f$ and $g$ are **multiplicative**.

So we only need to verify that the equality holds when $n$ is a power of a prime. 
Multiplicativity then atutomatically gives us the rest.

The number $p^k$ has $k+1$ divisors: in symbols, $d(p^k)=k+1$.

So we want to prove that for any $m$,
$$\sum_0^m (k+1)^3 =\left(\sum_0^m (k+1)\right)^2.$$
Look up the formula for the sum of the first $q$ cubes.

Comment: What is $m$? Just any arbitrary integer?

Comment: Yes, any integer $\ge 0$. You may be more familiar with $1^3+2^3+3^3+\cdots +n^3=\frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4}$, which says the same thing. If you don't know the result, it can be proved by induction.