# Show that $F(n)=\sum_{d|n} \tau(d)^3$ is multiplicative

Tags: number-theory

I need to show that

$$F(n)=\sum_{d|n} \tau(d)^3$$ 
and 
$$G(n)=\left(\sum_{d|n} \tau(d)\right)^2$$
are multiplicative

I know by definition $f$ is multiplicative if $f(mn) = f(m)f(n)$ but I do not know how to start showing $F(n)$ and $G(n)$ are multiplicative. Any help?

Comment: Surprisingly, $F=G$. See http://math.stackexchange.com/a/216698/589.

Comment: right and in order to show that F = G we must now that F and G are multiplicative but I am not sure how to show that

Answer (score 2):

If $\Psi$ is a multiplicative function then $\Psi^k$ is a multiplicative function, too.
 If $\Xi$ is another multiplicative function, [the Dirichlet convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_convolution) 
$$(\Xi * \Psi)(n) = \sum_{d\mid n}\Xi(d)\,\Psi\left(\frac{n}{d}\right) $$
is a multiplicative function, too. If we denote through $\mathbb{1}$ the arithmetic function that always equals one, we have $F=\tau^3*\mathbb{1}$ and $G=(\tau *\mathbb{1})^2$. It is not difficult to check that $F$ and $G$ agree on prime powers, hence $F\equiv G$. Since $\tau=\mathbb{1}*\mathbb{1}$, the proof can be stated in the following artistic form:

> $$ \left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}k\right)^2=\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^3\quad\Longrightarrow\quad (\mathbb{1}*\mathbb{1})^3*\mathbb{1}=(\mathbb{1}*\mathbb{1}*\mathbb{1})^2.$$