# Number of factors from factors of number.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Take a number, say 30.
Now, the factors of 30 are 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 10, 15, 30.

1 has 1 factor, 2 has 2, 3 has 2, 5 has 2, 6 has 4, 10 has 4, 15 has 4, and 30 has 8.

Observe that $(1+2+2+2+4+4+4+8)^2 = 1^3 + 2^3 + 2^3 + 2^3 + 4^3 + 4^3 + 4^3 + 8^3.$

Does this "interesting" property hold for other numbers as well?

Comment: I just ran a program to test every numbers between 1 and 10000, and it holds. Veryyy interesting.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/216698/78967

Comment: @mathlove Not sure whether this link is helpful. Here , we have a special collection of numbers , and the task is to show that all collections satisfy this very non-trivial property. For the case $1,2,\cdots , n$ , the identity is well known.

Comment: @Peter : You have to say the comment to the person who closed this question :) The link is to lhf's answer, not to that question. I knew that question is not duplicate.

Comment: technically it did answer the question. OP only wanted a confirmation of that identity and that link did it :)

Answer (score 3):

Given a positive integer $x$, denote the number of (positive) factors of $x$ by $\sigma_0(x)$. This function has the properties that $\sigma_0(p^k) = k+1$ if $p$ is prime, and $\sigma_0(xy) = \sigma_0(x) \sigma_0(y)$ if $\gcd(x,y)=1$.

Then the claim is that for a positive integer $n$,

$$ \left(\sum_{d \mid n} \sigma_0(d)\right)^2 = \sum_{d \mid n} \sigma_0(d)^3 $$

This is true for all $n$, by strong induction (or by induction on the number of prime factors of $n$).

If $n=1$, its only factor is $1$, and since $\sigma_0(1)=1$, $\sigma_0(1)^2 = \sigma_0(1)^3$.

Suppose $n>1$, and the claim is true for all positive integers smaller than $n$. $n$ is divisible by some prime $p$. Let $a$ be the largest natural number where $p^a \mid n$, and we know $a \geq 1$. Let $m$ be the positive integer $\frac{n}{p^a}$, and we know $m<n$ and $p \nmid m$.

The factors of $n$ are exactly the numbers of the form $p^b d$ where $0 \leq b \leq a$ and $d \mid m$.

$$ \begin{align*}
\left(\sum_{d \mid n} \sigma_0(d)\right)^2 &= \left(\sum_{d \mid m} \sum_{b=0}^a \sigma_0(p^b d)\right)^2 \\
&= \left(\sum_{d \mid m} \sum_{b=0}^a (b+1) \sigma_0(d)\right)^2 \\
&= \left( \frac{(a+1)(a+2)}{2} \sum_{d \mid m} \sigma_0(d)\right)^2 \\
&= \frac{(a+1)^2 (a+2)^2}{4} \left( \sum_{d \mid m} \sigma_0(d) \right)^2
\end{align*} $$

$$ \begin{align*}
\sum_{d \mid n} \sigma_0(d)^3 &= \sum_{d \mid m} \sum_{b=0}^a \sigma_0(p^b d)^3 \\
&= \sum_{d \mid m} \sum_{b=0}^a (b+1)^3 \sigma_0(d)^3 \\
&= \frac{(a+1)^2 (a+2)^2 }{4} \sum_{d \mid m} \sigma_0(d)^3
\end{align*} $$

Since $m<n$, these are equal by the inductive hypothesis, completing the induction proof.